# Pandas difference between dataframes on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

I couldn't find a way to have a dataframe that has the difference of 2 dataframes based on a column. So basically:

```
dfA = ID, val
      1, test
      2, other test

dfB = ID, val
      2, other test
```

I want to have a `dfC` that holds the difference `dfA - dfB` based on column `ID`

```
dfC = ID, val
      1, test
```

Comment: So you're looking for common rows in dfA and dfB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

merge the dataframe on ID

```
dfMerged = dfA.merge(dfB, left_on='ID', right_on='ID', how='outer') # defaults to inner join.
```

In the merged dataframe, name collisions are avoided using the suffix `_x` & `_y` to denote left and right source dataframes.

So, you'll end up with (most likely) `val_x` and `val_y`. compare these columns however you want to. For example:

```
dfMerged['x_y_test'] = dfMerged.val_y == dfMerged.val_x
# gives you a column with a comparison of val_x, val_y.
```

Use this as a mask to get to the desired `dfC` in your question.

Comment: The `merge` did the trick, but I thought it was more usefull to just do a `dfMerged.dropna()` after the merge and that will be the set with the difference.

Comment: yes, essentially, the answer was really about the `merge` method, which allows you to sql-like joins. The rest of the answer shows one way to compare fields. There are definitely more appropriate ways to achieve certain end results.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
dfC = dfB[dfB["ID"] == dfA["ID"]]
```

How about this:

```
dfC = dfB[dfB["ID"].isin(dfA["ID"])]
```

Comment: This would have been great, but: ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare